# How to intercept all requests to the specific page (on python for example)

Tags: python, linux, sniffer

Suppose I have an extension that send requests to pages `api.ext.com/addWord` and `api.ext.com/getTranscr`

Where to start to write an application that will intercept all requests to one page (the site will not receive them), but leave intact requests to other pages

Comment: I don't understand your question; What's the context here? What have you tried? What's the webserver?

Comment: Look into Netfilter: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NetfilterQueue/0.3 - this is how packet interception is mostly handled on Linux. You usually block by IP instead of domain, though.

Comment: @Matthew geniously, that`s what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008272/matthew), the answer on Linux is `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j DROP`